# Refresh On IPhone Device Using React-Native Tools

Tags: react-native

Im playing with React Native, and have deployed to my IPhone device (using 'option 1 in appdelegate with correct localhost)

I assume that I should be able to make changes to views in my text editor and have them 'refresh' on the phone (same as the simulator).

There seems no mechanism to do this on an actual device.

Have I missed something ? Or is CMD+R type refresh available only in the simulator

Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shaking the device should bring up the development menu, which allows you to manually refresh the app bundle (or enable live reload), and enable Safari/Chrome debugging.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/runningondevice.html